# Replace the characters with Image in string and then set to Textview

Tags: android, image, spannablestring

```
This is :) and want to :) replace with :D new image.
```

I have this type of string that is i have got from EditTextbox.NOw i want to replace all ":)" with image1 and ":D" with image2.I want to do like string.replaceall(":)",image1) and string.replaceall(":D",image2).So can anybody suggest me how to do this with small code and also better performance.I have write the code and it is working also fine but it takes much time.

```
textview.setText(getSmiledText(ctx, stringvalue));
private static final HashMap<String, Integer> emoticons = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    static {
        emoticons.put(":)", R.drawable.j1);
        emoticons.put(":D", R.drawable.j2);}

public static Spannable getSmiledText(Context context, String s) {
        int index;
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        builder.append(s);

        for (index = 0; index < builder.length(); index++) {
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
                int length = entry.getKey().length();
                if (index + length > builder.length())
                    continue;
                if (builder.subSequence(index, index + length).toString()
                        .equals(entry.getKey())) {
                    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, entry.getValue()),
                            index, index + length,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    index += length - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: `it is working also fine` so what was the question again ?

Comment: i need the better solution which will increase the performance.This is working but take much time bcz it will check character by character.So i need better solution

Comment: it seems that `setSpan` is the slowest part... I have the similar issue with replacing background colour of the text.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
public static Spannable getSmiledText(Context context, String s) 
    {
    int index;
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(s);

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : EmoticonsCode.emoticons_code.entrySet())
    {
        try {
           int length = entry.getKey().length();
           for ( index = s.indexOf(entry.getKey()); index >= 0; index = s.indexOf(entry.getKey(), index + 1))
           {
                System.out.println(index);
                builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, entry.getValue()), index, index + length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
   return builder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is just load the images earlier not at run time, load images and save in variables and just assign the images at run time. FYI characters is not the problem, i came through same issue earlier i understood it as touch points issue, but problem was loading of images.

Comment: can you explain more how to load image previosly? I have set the images like this emoticons.put(":)", R.drawable.j1);
        emoticons.put(":D", R.drawable.j2); so now how can i do?

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.j1);
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.j2);
builder.setSpan(bitmap,index, index + length,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

I hope this helps.

Comment: YOu can also put string and bitmap into your hashmap.

Comment: But if i have set the image in hashmap like R.draweable.j1 then what is the different between that and this bitmap

Comment: difference is you have already loaded the resource like this
emoticons.put(":)", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.j1));

Comment: okay so if just i write the R.drawable.j1 then it will not load the image but if i write BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.j1 then it will load the image right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17738/discussion-between-nency-and-jay)