# How to show iOS style Emoji characters in Android's EditText?

Tags: android, ios, emoji

First, the Emoji characters on Android look different then they are in iOS device. In Android, the Emoji characters are black and white, but in iOS, they look much better.

Some input methods support typing Emoji characters directly in Android devices. For this kind of input method, in Facebook, if I type an Emoji character, then the character is still displayed as the one in Android. But in WeChat, the Emoji character looks the same as iOS.

So my question is, how to implement the same function as WeChat? Please see below two snapshots, the first one is WeChat, then the second one is Facebook.

Thanks a lot.

WeChat:

[image: WeChat]

Facebook:

[image: Facebook]

Comment: You need to use the same font.

Comment: no, i don't think WeChat uses any special fonts.

Comment: If you did figure it out, please share with us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out the method to replace the unicode character with corresponding Emoji image. Here is the github link of my library/sample project. Enjoy. :-)

https://github.com/IPL/iOSStyleEditText

Answer (score 1):

You need to download all Emoji images, keep it local in your application and replace the unicodes of smileys with Emoji images in your EditText/TextView.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795101/replace-the-characters-with-image-in-string-and-then-set-to-textview) shows one of the ways to add images inline with text in an EditText/TextView.

Comment: Thanks for the link, although it does not answer my question exactly.

Comment: +1 This should be the selected answer, as it is the way to go, unless you want to use a custom font that includes the colorful emoji.